# Menu lateral en Kotlin no funciona (onNavigationItemSelected)

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

muy buenas, queria comentar mi problema, me compre una plantilla base, la cual tiene un menu lateral, pero no tenia ningun boton del mismo (el configurado en el xml) configurado en la parte de kotlin, luego de varias investigando encontre como poder añadir la funcion, pero no logre hacerlo funcionar, este es mi codigo:
en `onCreate`:

```
binding.drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
binding.navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)
actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState()
```

fuera:

```
private fun closeDrawer() {
    binding.drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
}
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    val id = item.itemId
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)

}

override fun onNavigationItemSelected(menuItem: MenuItem): Boolean {
    closeDrawer()
        when (menuItem.getItemId()) {
            R.id.ic_instagram -> {
                val intent = Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW",
                    Uri.parse("https://www.instagram.com/"))
                val b = Bundle()
                b.putBoolean("new_window", true) //sets new window
                intent.putExtras(b)
                startActivity(intent)
                true
            }
            else -> false

        }

    return true
}
```

Me gustaria saber en que estoy fallando, porque al hacer click en el id `ic_instagram` por ejemplo, no cumple ninguna funcion y solo cierra el menu.